# Unable to update PostgrSQL table using psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to update a table using psycopg2 library since I need to bulk update that column.
When I run

```
tr_cursor.execute("UPDATE <table-name> set <column-name> = 'KR' where id = 21;")
```

The command runs in < 1 second but it DOES NOT update the table. When I run the same command in datagrip it takes more than 4minutes to run (I stopped it at 4min, did NOT let it run fully. Just wanted to check the time required). What am I doing wrong here? Please ask for any further info that is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you might be missing a `conn.commit()` atter your UPDATE statement.
`conn` being what you created with the `conn=psycopg2.connect(...` call.

It is the default behavior for all database statements with psycopg. Of course for select you don't need it, as there is nothing to commit. But it is a parameter you can change, check the autocommit option: http://psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit

Comment: Ya, I think that's it. I don't have that in my code

Comment: Is that necessary for all statements or just UPDATE?

Comment: You usually want to `commit` a transaction when you're making a modification to a DB table. So that should be used for CREATE / UPDATE / DELETE :) ... Unless you set `conn.autocommit = True` at the beginning

Comment: If it runs very quickly in Python compared to Datagrip, perhaps it doesn't really hit any rows. Print cursor.rowcount just after the delete to confirm.

Comment: I recommend using Psycopg2 connections as context managers. Then transactions will be committed if they succeed and rolled back if not.